# Using python to add protocol to Wireshark capture

Tags: python, wireshark, encapsulation, pcap

For the last number of years I've been using Wireshark to successfully capture and analyse samples of network traffic. I then typically need to modify this capture file by encapsulating it within a GTP layer such that I can post process the pcap with a proprietary tool. I have always achieved this successfully in the linux environment using a python script adding a "fixed" GTP headed to each TCP / UDP packet utilising something like

```
import sys
import dpkt
from dpkt.ip import IP
from dpkt.udp import UDP
from optparse import OptionParser
import struct
import socket
# from pcapy import *

ETHERNET_SRC = "\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06"
ETHERNET_DST = "\xA1\xA2\xA3\xA4\xA5\xA6"

GGSN_IP_SRC= "\xd5\xe9\x82\x38"      #"213.233.130.56"
GGSN_IP_DST= "\xd5\xe9\x82\x37"      #"213.233.130.55"

userip = None
global_userip = "\x0a\x44\x17\x5b"
total_packets_writes = 0
pcap_writer = None

# pcap file pid383_session1_272017012778276.pcap is on the Destkop

# GTP HEADER FOR CREATE PDP CONTEXT

# TID \x84\xba\x40\x11 for downstream
# TID 81fbe032 for upstream 
# ip client 0a 44 17 5b 

gtp_pdp_context_request = "\x32\x10\x00\xa1\x00\x00\x00\x00\x20\xac\x00\x00\x02\x72\x02\x71"\
    "\x10\x72\x87\x72\xf6\x0f\xfc\x10\x84\xba\x40\x11\x11\x80\xce\x00"\
    "\x11\x14\x0a\x80\x00\x02\xf1\x21\x83\x00\x15\x05\x74\x65\x73\x74"\
    "\x31\x02\x68\x73\x08\x76\x6f\x64\x61\x66\x6f\x6e\x65\x02\x69\x65"\
    "\x84\x00\x1d\x80\xc0\x23\x06\x01\x06\x00\x06\x00\x00\x80\x21\x10"\
    "\x01\x01\x00\x10\x81\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x83\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00"\
    "\x85\x00\x04\xd5\xe9\x82\x38\x85\x00\x04\xd5\xe9\x82\x38\x86\x00"\
    "\x07\x91\x53\x83\x97\x23\x75\x33\x87\x00\x0f\x02\x22\x92\x1f\x93"\
    "\x96\xfe\xfe\x74\x05\x01\x01\x00\x4f\x00\x97\x00\x01\x01\x98\x00"\
    "\x08\x01\x72\xf2\x10\x0b\xcc\xcc\x65\x99\x00\x02\x40\x01\x9a\x00"\
    "\x08\x53\x88\x85\x40\x19\x74\x27\x50"


gtp_pdp_context_response="\x32\x11\x00\x57\x80\xce\x00\x11\x20\xac\x00\x00\x01\x80\x08\xfe"\
    "\x10\x81\xfb\xe0\x32\x11\x95\xca\x80\x32\x7f\x10\x9b\xfb\x08\x80"\
    "\x00\x06\xf1\x21"   "\x0a\x44\x17\x5b"     "\x84\x00\x14\x80\x80\x21\x10\x03"\
    "\x01\x00\x10\x81\x06\x59\x13\x40\xa4\x83\x06\x59\x13\x40\x24\x85"\
    "\x00\x04\xd5\xe9\x82\x37\x85\x00\x04\xd5\xe9\x82\x37\x87\x00\x0f"\
    "\x02\x22\x92\x1f\x93\x96\xfe\xfe\x74\x05\x01\x01\x00\x4f\x00"


gtp_pdp_user_data_up = "\x30\xff\x00\x3c\x81\xfb\xe0\x32"
gtp_pdp_user_data_down = "\x30\xff\x00\x3c\x80\xce\x00\x11"


# GTP HEADER FOR PDP UPDATE
"""
0000   32 12 00 3f 95 ca 80 32 20 ad 00 00 10 84 ba 40
0010   11 14 0a 85 00 04 d5 e9 82 38 85 00 04 d5 e9 82
0020   38 87 00 0f 02 22 92 1f 93 96 fe fe 74 05 01 01
0030   00 4a 00 97 00 01 01 98 00 08 01 72 f2 10 0b cc
0040   cc 65 99 00 02 40 01"""

def parseOptions():
        """Parse the user options"""

        usage = "Usage: %prog [options]"

        p = OptionParser(usage)

        p.add_option("-f", "--pcapfile", dest="pcapfile", 
                help="Pcapfile for add the GTP header.")

        p.add_option("-i", "--userip", dest="userip", 
                help="User IP address.")

        p.add_option("-r", "--remove", dest="remove",action="store_true", 
                help="Remove the GTP layer.")

        p.add_option("-v", "--verbose",action="count",dest="verbose",default=0,
                help="Shows extra information.")
        return p


def generatePdpContextRequest(w):
    eth = dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(src=ETHERNET_SRC,dst=ETHERNET_DST)
    udp = UDP(sport=1024, dport=2123,data = gtp_pdp_context_request)
    ip = IP(src=GGSN_IP_SRC,dst=GGSN_IP_DST, data = udp)

    ip.p = 17 
    ip.data = udp
    ip.len = 8 + 20 + len(gtp_pdp_context_request) 
    udp.ulen = 8 + len(gtp_pdp_context_request)
    eth.data = ip

    w.writepkt(eth)

def generatePdpContextResponse(w):
        eth = dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(src=ETHERNET_DST,dst=ETHERNET_SRC)
        udp = UDP(sport=2123, dport=1024,data = gtp_pdp_context_response)
        ip = IP(src=GGSN_IP_DST,dst=GGSN_IP_SRC,data=udp)
        #ip = IP (dst='\x01\x02\x03\x04', src='\x05\x06\x07\x08',data = udp)

        ip.p = 17
        ip.data = udp
        ip.len = 8 + 20 + len(gtp_pdp_context_response)
        udp.ulen = 8 + len(gtp_pdp_context_response)
        eth.data = ip

        w.writepkt(eth)

def generateUserData(w,isUp,length,data):

    if(isUp):
        srceth= ETHERNET_SRC
        dsteth= ETHERNET_DST
        srcip = GGSN_IP_SRC
        dstip = GGSN_IP_DST
        gtp_header = "\x30\xff" + struct.pack(">h",length) + "\x81\xfb\xe0\x32" 
        srcport = 1024
        dstport = 2152
    else:
        srceth= ETHERNET_DST
        dsteth= ETHERNET_SRC
        srcip = GGSN_IP_DST
        dstip = GGSN_IP_SRC
        gtp_header = "\x30\xff" + struct.pack(">h",length) + "\x84\xba\x40\x11"
        srcport = 2152 
        dstport = 1024 

    f_data = gtp_header + data
    f_length = 8 + length

    udp = UDP(sport = srcport,dport=dstport,data=f_data)
    ip = IP(src=srcip,dst=dstip,data = udp)
    eth = dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(src=srceth,dst=dsteth,data = ip)

    ip.p = 17
    ip.len = 20 + 8+ f_length
    udp.ulen = 8 + f_length

    w.writepkt(eth) 

def processPcapFile(filename):

    total_packets = 0
    total_packets_writes = 0
    total_packets_nowrites = 0
    total_bogus_packets = 0

    pcap=dpkt.pcap.Reader(file(filename,"rb"))

    try:
        for ts, buf in pcap:
            total_packets += 1
            if pcap.datalink() == dpkt.pcap.DLT_LINUX_SLL:
                l2 = dpkt.sll.SLL(buf)
                else:
                l2 = dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(buf)

            raw_data = l2.data

            if (str(type(l2.data)) != "<class 'dpkt.ip.IP'>"):
                """ Check for other types of encapsulation """
                if (str(type(l2.data)) == "<class 'dpkt.pppoe.PPPoE'>"):
                    raw_data = l2.data.ppp.ip 
                else:   
                    total_bogus_packets += 1
                    continue

            ip = raw_data 

            if(socket.inet_ntoa(ip.src) == userip):
                direction = True
                newip = IP(src=global_userip,dst=ip.dst,p=ip.p,len=ip.len,data=ip.data)
                generateUserData(pcap_writer,direction,ip.len,str(newip))   
                total_packets_writes += 1
            elif(socket.inet_ntoa(ip.dst) == userip):
                direction = False
                total_packets_writes += 1
                newip = IP(src=ip.src,dst=global_userip,p=ip.p,len=ip.len,data=ip.data)
                generateUserData(pcap_writer,direction,ip.len,str(newip))   
            else:
                total_packets_nowrites += 1
    except:
        e = sys.exc_info()[0]
            print("ERROR during processing packets:",e, " packet:",total_packets)

    print "Total bogus packets>:", total_bogus_packets
    print "Total user packets writes:",total_packets_writes
    print "Total nonuser packets    :",total_packets_nowrites


def removeGTPLayerFromPcapfile(filename):

        total_packets_writes = 0
        total_bogus_packets = 0

    f = open("%sGTP.pcap" % filename ,"w")
    writer = dpkt.pcap.Writer(f)

    pcap=dpkt.pcap.Reader(file(filename,"rb"))

        for ts, buf in pcap:
                if pcap.datalink() == dpkt.pcap.DLT_LINUX_SLL:
                        l2 = dpkt.sll.SLL(buf)
                else:
                        l2 = dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(buf)


                if (str(type(l2.data)) != "<class 'dpkt.ip.IP'>"):
                        total_bogus_packets += 1
                        continue

                ip = l2.data
        udp = ip.data
        gtp = udp.data

        gtp_length = int(gtp[0])
        # print "%d %x" % (gtp_length,gtp_length)
        if (gtp_length ==0):
            offset = 8
        else:
            offset = 12
            eth = dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(src=ETHERNET_DST,dst=ETHERNET_SRC,data=gtp[offset:])
        writer.writepkt(eth) 

        total_packets_writes += 1

    writer.close()
    f.close()

        print "Total bogus packets>:", total_bogus_packets
        print "Total packets writes:",total_packets_writes


if __name__ == "__main__":

        parser = parseOptions()
        (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
        if(options.pcapfile == None):
                parser.error("Argument is required")
                sys.exit(1)

    if (options.remove == True):
        print "Removing GTP Layer from pcapfile."
        removeGTPLayerFromPcapfile(options.pcapfile)                
        sys.exit(0)

        if(options.userip == None):
                parser.error("Argument is required")
                sys.exit(1)

    userip = options.userip

    f = open("%sGTP.pcap" % options.pcapfile ,"w")
    pcap_writer = dpkt.pcap.Writer(f)

    generatePdpContextRequest(pcap_writer)
    generatePdpContextResponse(pcap_writer)

    processPcapFile(options.pcapfile)

    pcap_writer.close()
    f.close()

    sys.exit(0)
```

[Wireshark Printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YuCc.jpg)

As I mentioned this always operated successfully in the linux environment whereby each additional GTP header was correctly interporated as Hex , however my problem is I need to port this to windows and now suddenly my additional GTP headers are being interporated as ascii instead of hex which is resulting in an invalid resultant pcap. I'm wondering if this is something related to Winpcap V Libpcap or if there are other causes and indeed if anyone has any suggestions on how to resolve this.

kind regards

Mandraker

Comment: It might help us if you could reduce that into a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and possible add a mininmal example of the data that you are parsing.

Comment: Python 2 or 3?   Could it be as simple as specifying those strings as bytes? ```gtp_header = b"\x30\xff" + struct.pack(">h",length) + b"\x84\xba\x40\x11"```.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I'm using Python 2.7 in all cases but additionally it's important to remember that the script , the source pcap for the purposes of this verification are always the same. The only possible variations are python modules, for example I use "dpkt" python module in both environments (but with slightly different versions..ie: linux V windows). I've updated the script above to include all the script.

Comment: Additionally I'm attaching a printscreen of what the script is being used to insert and where. Originally the pcap ip conversation ( in this case SSL) had no GTP layer protocol ...but with the script a hex sequence (representing the GTP protocol ) is inserted at 0030 in the screenshot.